# Recursive function call in angular 6 caused maximum call stack size execeed issue

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using angular 6 prime ng library treeNode.
I wanted to create a copy on node which is more than 1000 children.

But when i am trying to achieve the same with recursion call, it results in to maximum call stack size increased.

Can anyone help me solving this issue.

```
createCopyOfTreeNode(originalTreeNode, parentTreeNode?) {
    const duplicateTreeNodeData = $.extend(true, {}, originalTreeNode.data);
    const duplicateTreeNode = new TreeNode();

    duplicateTreeNode.label = originalTreeNode.label;
    duplicateTreeNode.icon = originalTreeNode.icon;
    duplicateTreeNode.assetType = originalTreeNode.assetType;

    duplicateTreeNode.expandedIcon = originalTreeNode.expandedIcon;
    duplicateTreeNode.collapsedIcon = originalTreeNode.collapsedIcon;
    duplicateTreeNode.leaf = originalTreeNode.leaf;
    duplicateTreeNode.selectable = originalTreeNode.selectable;
    duplicateTreeNode.data = duplicateTreeNodeData;
    if (parentTreeNode) {
        if (!parentTreeNode.children) {
            parentTreeNode.children = [];
        }
        parentTreeNode.children.push(duplicateTreeNode);
    }
    if (originalTreeNode.children && originalTreeNode.children.length > 0) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            originalTreeNode.children.forEach(originalTreeNodeChild => {
                this.createCopyOfTreeNode(originalTreeNodeChild, duplicateTreeNode);
            });
        }, 0);
    }
    return duplicateTreeNode;


    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` methods for creating copy of object.

For example:

```
const duplicateNode = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalNode));
```

Comment: As node is nested type, the solution you have provided does not do deep copy.
And result into circular reference error, and i push the this duplicate node inside the selectedCurrent. I have tried this solution, but it did not work.

I have found trampoline, but not sure how to implement it wr.t my problem